# error: resource color/com_facebook_messenger_blue not found

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

When i build my app (i tried both clean build and rebuild both) it showed AAPT2 error, so i ran assembleDebug from gradle tab on the left side which showed the fallowing error

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: resource color/com_facebook_messenger_blue (aka com.example.itachi.com.pbr:color/com_facebook_messenger_blue) not found.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\ITACHI\\Downloads\\Scrof\\PBR\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\styles.xml"}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
```

so as the path suggested in the error i checked the styles.xml file in values folder which is as follows

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/com_facebook_messenger_blue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>


<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<style name="DrawerHamburgerStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/black</item>
</style>


<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Can anyone tell me where i did wrong?

Comment: If that is not your app `styles.xml` file, create a new color in `colors.xml`, calling it colorPrimay, it will override the one declared in your dependency. If it is your style file instead, simply change color, or add a color called `com_facebook_messenger_blue`

Comment: its not mine, my friend send that to me as a zip file

Comment: can you please elaborate the solution .

Comment: Try adding this line `<color name="com_facebook_messenger_blue">#0084ff</color>` in your `colors.xml` file

Comment: Thanks for the help it worked but I still don't understand why it went wrong so, if you can explain me I will write the answer else please write the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said in the comments, you are including a dependency that should be a jar or aar file. It was built with a dependency on the Facebook SDK I guess, since the name of the missing resource.

When you build an aar files it doesn't contain the dependencies that it needs, but you have to provide them in your `build.gradle` file.

To make it work then either you declare the missing dependency in your project or as I suggested in this case you could simply add the missing resource in your `colors.xml` file.

```
<color name="com_facebook_messenger_blue">#0084ff</color>
```

This way when your project is compiling, it is able to provide the missing resource to your archive library. I hope it is enough clear now.

Answer (score 1):

In you code, seems you called a color named after 'com_facebook_messenger_blue' from your colors.xml file.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/com_facebook_messenger_blue</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

and the error refers that, there is no color named after 'com_facebook_messenger_blue' in colors.xml file.

so,

go to res > values and open colors.xml file. then add this line of code in the 
`<resource>...</resource>` tag.

```
<color name="com_facebook_messenger_blue">#your desired color code</color>
```

remember to put the color code.